# How to display a select only when other select's option was chosen?-

Tags: laravel

I have 2 selects on a page and i want to show the 2nd only when in the first select a specific option was chosen, is that possible in laravel? here the code:

```
            <select class="form-select my-2" name="category_id">
            <option disabled selected>Seleziona una categoria</option>
            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}" @if ($category->id == old('category_id')) selected @endif>
                    {{ $category->name }}
                </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

        <select class="form-select my-2" name="type_id">
            <option disabled selected>Seleziona un tipo di sushi</option>
            @foreach ($types as $type)
                <option value="{{ $type->id }}" @if ($type->id == old('type_id')) selected @endif>
                    {{ $type->name }}
                </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
```

Comment: Easy in Livewire

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery  :

```
<script>
    $('select[name="category_id"]').change(function (){
        let categoryId = $(this).val();
        if (categoryId == null)
        {
            $('select[name="type_id"]').hide();
        }else{
            $('select[name="type_id"]').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```